# Unable to work with aiogram package in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-poetry, aiogram

I am trying to install the aiogram package with Poetry, but I am getting the following error:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.9"
aiogram = {url = "https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/archive/refs/heads/dev-3.x.zip"}
```

I have also tried to install the package with Python 3.11, but I got the same error.

I have already checked that the aiogram package is available in the PyPI repository, and I have also checked that the Python version I am using is compatible with the package.

What is the problem?

Comment: "the following error" - where is the error? What you have shown does not look like an error.